# Silverlight Binding Array Element to a Textblock

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding

```
    private int[] g1 = new int[9];

    public int[] G1 
    { 
        get { return g1; }
        set { NotifyPropertyChanged("G1[]"); }
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }



    <TextBlock x:Name="R1G1" Text="{Binding G1[0]}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" Height="80"/>
```

G1 is filled with integers from 1 to 9 in a method.

Problem:
Text of the textblock is set to 0 and they can not be updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("G1[]");
```

should be

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("G1");
```

Are you sure the array contains the values 1 to 9? It doesn't show in the code.

TextBlocks can't be used to input text. Use a TextBox instead.

The binding might need a `Mode=TwoWay`

and finally (not needed for this problem): an array does not support sending notifications of changes to the array (element added, removed, moved) You could use an ObservableCollection for that.

Answer (score 0):

Woah...Stop! Use an `ObservableCollection<int>` instead of an array. An ObservableCollection implements INotify.